# How to pipe objects to a specific parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to list all my PowerShell functions from one directory. The following command works:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ($env:USERPROFILE + "\somewhere\*.psm1") -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Command -Module $_.BaseName}
```

Now I tried to pipe the output from `Get-ChildItem` directly to the cmdlet `Get-Command`. Something like this, which does not work:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ($env:USERPROFILE + "\somewhere\*.psm1") -Recurse | Get-Command -Module {$_.BaseName}
```

Obviously, I do not really understand how to pipe the object from `Get-ChildItem` in the correct way to the parameter `-Module` in `Get-Command`.

I have two questions:

- Do you have a hint how to pipe correctly?
- Is it possible to pipe to a specific parameter like `-Module` or is the object always handed over to one default parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters can be bound in four different ways:

- By location in the argument list, e.g., `Get-ChildItem C:\` (only certain parameters)
- By name in the argument list, e.g. `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\`
- By value from the pipeline, e.g. `1..5 | Get-Random` (only certain parameters)
- By name from the pipeline, e.g. `'C:\Windows' | Get-ChildItem` (only certain parameters)

You can inspect the various ways of parameter binding via `Get-Help <command> -Parameter *`. You can then see that `Get-Command` allows the `Module` parameter to be bound only by property name:

```
-Module [<String[]>]
    Specifies an array of modules. ...

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                none
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

So the input has to be an object that has a `Module` property, to allow binding. In your case you thus need an additional step in between:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ($env:USERPROFILE + "\somewhere\*.psm1") -Recurse |
  Select-Object @{l='Module';e={$_.Basename}} |
  Get-Command
```

Now, this instance here is something that's a bit annoying, since the `Module` parameter is bound by property name, but most things don't give you an object with a `Module` property. Heck, even `Get-Module` doesn't have that, since the returned object uses `Name` as the property name, so you can't even do

```
Get-Module | Get-Command
```

However, in many other places (notably concerning paths) work very well automatically. And if you can control your input objects, e.g. when reading from CSV or other data sources, you can end up with rather nice and concise code.

**EDIT:** Ansgar Wiechers notes that, while this *should* work, it doesn't, actually. This may be a shortfall of PowerShell's parameter binding algorithm (which is quite complex, as seen above, and we never got it to work correctly in Pash either), or maybe the `Get-Command` cmdlet has parameters described in a way that simply cannot allow binding because of reasons.

Comment: I too thought that a calculated property should work, but it didn't when I just tested it (Server 2012 R2, PowerShell v4). Instead it failed with an error "Get-Command : The term '@{Module=SomeModule}' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Comment: Side note: while `Get-Module | Get-Command` doesn't work, `Get-Command` accepts an array for the module parameter, and modules have a conversion to string, so `Get-Command -Module (Get-Module)` *does* work. (Of course, this is not directly relevant to OP's case, just goes to show that there are usually many ways in PowerShell.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: This is also pointed out specifically in the documentation of the parameter, but as you note, not relevant here since it doesn't involve parameter binding via the pipeline.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Indeed. Now that's a bit inconvenient :/ ... could be that property name binding is advertised, but doesn't work properly?

Comment: Looks pretty much like it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That´s nice, I even didn't know that this is possible. So, this solve my problem in an appropriate way, because I do not need loops and can send an array to `Get-Command`. Probably you should answer this question with your idea as an alternative solution?

Comment: @Dirk: I don't actually like it as an alternative solution because it's inherently less efficient. Piping works with any number of objects; creating an array consumes memory linear to the number of items you're processing. This is not actually a problem here (I don't think you have millions of modules lying around...) but your question is about piping, and my approach explicitly avoids that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ok, I'm not familiar in depth with the pros and cons, because I simply want to get rid of the loop. Fortunately, I learned much about piping. :)